# Is there any IL editor to change the bytecode of an assembly?

Tags: .net, bytecode, il, disassembly

I've detected some defects on legacy third party assemblies that we're using on our code decompilind them. I would like to fix them but as I don't have the source code I need to directly modify the bytecode. The changes are really simple (changing an AND for an OR and NOPing some lines).

Is there an editor to do this kind of things? Doing the work with an hex editor would be the last option, I would preffer to have a hint of what instructions I have around the cursor ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) with the [Reflexil](http://www.reflector.net/add-ins/) add-on. Take a look at the screenshots, it's pretty powerful and it can modify IL code at runtime. Reflector used to be free of charge, you might be able to get some older version somewhere.

Comment: Amazing! That's what I was looking for. Looks amazing and I have an old copy still working. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[`dnSpy`](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy), allows you to modify IL and C# code. See their [screenshots](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy#picture-time).

Comment: Wow!! This is perfect! Thanks.

Comment: This really helped me thank you! I needed to make a change to a legacy app we wrote a very long time ago that demonstrated some technology we want to integrate into new product. And I needed a simple tweak to the old app to get it working. Awesome tool

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming the assemblies are not strongly named because otherwise there's nothing you can do without the signing key.

If not, it sounds like [`Ildasm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) would work for you. You can decompile the assemblies, perform modifications and assemble them again with [`Ilasm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx).

Another free option might be Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx), which *"can create a Visual Studio project from a decompiled assembly."* -- I haven't used it, but this sounds like it decompiles to source and creates a ready-to-build project. That would be super convenient since you won't even have to work with IL.

Comment: Not at all. It does not allow you to edit the bytecode. I need to edit the bytecode. Building the whole assembly is not an option.

Comment: Because the whole code is "source obfuscated" and cannot be compiled without a really high effort and because decompilers never create code that can be compiled again without dedicating a high amount of time to that task.

Comment: If the code is disassembled to IL, then it should be possible to reassemble it again without issue. This is not the same as decompiling, which, as you say, is not always capable of producing code that will recompile cleanly.

Comment: @SoMoS `ildasm` followed by `ilasm` **cannot** fail to work on a managed assembly. CIL **is** the 'bytecode'.

Comment: @AakashM: I want to edit the bytecode of an assembly. CIL is not the bytecode, 00 94 3E 34 2F IS the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Try Simple Assembly Explorer, it allows you to edit bytecode and works by default more life Reflexil

https://sites.google.com/site/simpledotnet/simple-assembly-explorer